# Can not add CURDify menu to sitemap in lift

Tags: scala, lift, lift-mapper

I have sitemap code like that:

```
object Site {
    val booksMenus   = Book.menus
    val authorsMenus   = Author.menus
    val publishersMenus   = Publisher.menus

    def sitemap = SiteMap(
         home          >> LocGroup("lg1"),
         static,
}
```

I want to add LocGroup to my menus and add them to sitemap
for example booksMenus is List[Menu] doing that as first answer suggested

```
booksMenus.map(_ >>LockGroup("lb"))
```

can not be possible because appending Loc only for Menuable not Menu type 
There is anyway to do that?

Answer (score 0):

`value >> is not a member of List[net.liftweb.sitemap.Menu]`

That means you should assign "group markers" to menu members, not to list of them. For example, smth like this:

`booksMenus.map(x=> x >> LogGroup("lg1"))`

Comment: gives erorr `value >> is not a member of net.liftweb.sitemap.Menu`

Comment: hmm, yes, my note was about the most obvious fix, but I forgot to check if there is a `>>` method on `Menu`. Seems like you should add "LockParams" (`>>`) earlier. That is, when the `Book.menus` is constructed. Where does it come from? Does it have something like 'lockParams' that can be overriden by you?

Comment: For example, there is a Lift's module "LogChanger" that has a Menu entry which you can be integrated in your site-s custom menu. Here's the way how the LogChanger allows to do that:
https://github.com/lift/modules/blob/master/widgets/src/main/scala/net/liftweb/widgets/logchanger/LogLevelChanger.scala#L174
An empty `lockParams`s is used by default, but you can override the method before using.

Comment: `Book.menus` come from CURDify trait in mapper I have to take a look thanks for your response

Comment: now its easy to change `LocGroup` but the result still `List[Menu]` there is any way to append it to `SiteMap`? I tried `:_*` but not works

Comment: do it in 2 steps: `val listTotal = list1 ::: list2`  and  `val sitemap = SiteMap(listTotal: _*)`